# Convert DER encoded certificate to ssh-rsa public key

Tags: powershell, vbscript, x509, ssh-keys, pki

I am working on a project to automate extracting a public key DER encoded certificate from a users smart card, and convert it to ssh-rsa public key form. The ssh-rsa public key would then be published as a user attribute in AD. From there puppet would grab the ssh public key using an ldap query and place it in the authorized_keys file for the user in question.

The problem I am running into is that in Windows there doesn't seem to be a way to make the conversion from DER encoded .cer file to a ssh-rsa key.  If the certificate is moved to the users home directory then it is possible to run:

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in username.cer -noout -pubkey > username.pub
```

Then ssh-keygen can create the ssh-rsa public key using:

```
ssh-keygen -f username.pub -i -m PKCS8
```

So does anyone know of a way for windows to make this conversion? If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the DER encoded file to PEM first.  Here is what you would need to do:

```
openssl x509 -in <your DER encoded File> -inform DER -out username.crt -outform PEM
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you need to use:

```
Import-Certificate
```

To import the certificate into the users/local machine store. You can then get the public key like so (well this gets the public key for every cert that has one, so change it to suite your needs):

```
((get-childitem cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse) | Where-Object{$_.PublicKey}).GetPublicKey()
```

This is using PowerShell 3.